# GET request with $resource returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.newPost.content = "Part 2 of phrase"
$scope.newPost.content = Phrase.get({id: $scope.newPost.phrase_id}).$promise.then(
  (result) ->
    return result.content + " " + $scope.newPost.content 
)

console.log($scope.newPost.content)
```

This should output my concatenated string. Instead $scope.newPost.content returns:

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/posts.json 422 (Unprocessable Entity) //content cant be blank
```

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in misunderstanding how promises work
It was solved by defining or instantiating the variable outside of the promise
You can then make changes to it inside the then() block and the changes will still be in effect outside of the then()

Working example looks like:

```
   $scope.newPost.content = "Part 2 of phrase";
    Phrase.get({id: $scope.newPost.phrase_id}).$promise.then(function(result){
        $scope.newPost.content = result.content + " " + $scope.newPost.content; 
    });

    console.log($scope.newPost.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common mistake, promises are a bit difficult to get a grasp at the beginning.

I'm gonna try to explain line by line, the order below is the same order that will happen running your code.

1) $scope.newPost.content = "Part 2 of phrase"

With this, you've assigned a string to your newPost.content variable, so far, so good

2) $scope.newPost.content = Phrase.get({bla bla bla ...});

Now this is replacing the previous string by an promise object, it's no longer a string.
Such thing is possible due to javascript crazy-flexible non-strongly typed way, lol. This will not wait for the get on the server to finish, and that's what's messing with you, the next line will run immediately after this, and will have the wrong value.

3) console.log($scope.newPost.content)

This is where things get messy, right now, your newPost.content is not a string, it is the promise from 2, and the output on the console proves that. (that output is a promise object).

Your newPost.content will only have your concatenated string when the promise at 2 resolves, it can take a long or short time to do it, the important thing to notice is that it is not blocking the rest of the code, so the 3 will execute immediately after the 2...
Think at the promise as something that is running in another thread.

So, my original answer remains, your variable will only have the desired value after the promise resolves, so you must take action after that, normally inside the then function, I made a few changes to illustrate that and avoid useless assingments:

```
var part2 = "Part 2 of phrase"
Phrase.get({id: $scope.newPost.phrase_id}).$promise.then(
  function(result){
      $scope.newPost.content = result.content + ' ' + part2;
      console.log($scope.newPost.content);
  }
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I changed the question to be more specific about what I was trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` line is outside the asynchronous call which means it will run before the resource has been retrieved.

- The order of events in your code is:

  1. Assign a string to `scope.newPost.content`
  2. Begin retrieving the resource.
  3. Assign a new value to `scope.newPost.content` with the immediate return of get, which looks like a promise object.
  4. Write this promise object to the console log.
  5. Receive the result of the resource get call.
  6. Assign the result of this call to `scope.newPost.content`

As you should see items 4 - 6 are not in the order that you are hoping.

If you want to write the result of the asynchronous call, it needs to happen after the promise has been resolved. The easiest place to do this is in the `then` callback function.

Comment: Sorry about that…fixed.